# Python word guessing game not solving if full-word guess is provided

Tags: python

It's working pretty well but when I try to guess the whole word, instead of just a letter, it doesn't recognize anything past the first letter of the input.

I'm thinking the issue is somewhere around line 41, but I'm not entirely sure. Do I need to define an entirely new function for if a complete word is guessed?

```
import random



 def choose_eng_word():
    
       eng_wb = ["world", "woman", "place", "group", "problem", "house", "system", "thing", "point", "family", "fact", "money", "child", "water", "state", "month", "person", "company", "hand", "part", "instance", "government", "number", "question", "issue", "service", "friend", "example", "business", "job", "complication", "authority", "government", "development", "education", "community", "president", "hospital", "information", "research", "history", "communication", "experience", "decision", "support", "understanding", "relationship", "variation", "daughter"]
    
        eng_word = random.choice(eng_wb).upper()
    
        return eng_word
    
    def eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, guesses):
        eng_word_in_prog = "" 
        for letter in eng_word:
            if letter in guesses:
                eng_word_in_prog += letter
            else:
                eng_word_in_prog += "*"
        return eng_word_in_prog
    
    
    
    def eng_main(eng_word):
        lettersguessed = []
        chances = int(len(eng_word) + 4)
        print("you are looking for a word that is " + str(len(eng_word)) + " letters long.")
    
        while True:
            if chances != 0:
                print("\nYou have " + str(chances) + " chances left.")
                print("Word so far: " + eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed))
                print("letters guessed: " + str(lettersguessed))
                guess = input("Guess: ").upper()[0]
    
                if guess not in lettersguessed:
                    lettersguessed.append(guess)
        
                if eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed) == eng_word:
                    print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the correct word: " + eng_word)
                    break
                else:
                    chances -=1
                    if guess in eng_word:
                        print("Correct Letter!)")
                    else:
                        print("Incorrect! Guess again!")
            else:
                print("\nWhoops! You ran out of guesses. The correct word was " + eng_word)
                break
    

while True:
    eng_word = choose_eng_word()
    eng_main(eng_word) 
    if input("Would you like to continue?").lower().startswith("n"):
        break
```

I tried changing a bit of the language around Line 41, since it's the area that references guessing a word, but anything I tried broke the code and I had to revert it to the original.

Comment: guess = input("Guess: ").upper()[0]

This line of code takes the very first letter of your list as a guess. So if you want the whole word remove the [0] from the end: guess = input("Guess: ").upper()

Also, this way your logic will get messed up. You can ask user if they want to guess the whole word or they want to do it by character and then you make different logics for each scenerio.

Comment: I'm not sure what's up with the formatting after I put the code in on here, it's not keeping it's original formatting that I copied over.

Comment: Select the code from import random to break and press ctrl+K and your code should be indented properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve some things like:

- Remove the [0] indexing from the input("Guess: ").upper() line to allow the input to be a complete word.
- If the guess is equal to the entire word, it checks if it's correct and breaks the loop if it is.
- If the guess is a single letter, it continues the previous logic for checking if the letter is correct and updating the display.

Maybe you can improve the following part of your code.
Where you do this:

```
...
if guess == eng_word:
    print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the correct word: " + eng_word)
    break
elif len(guess) == 1 and guess not in lettersguessed:
    lettersguessed.append(guess)
    if guess in eng_word:
        print("Correct Letter!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect! Guess again!")
    if eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed) == eng_word:
        print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the correct word: " + eng_word)
        break
    chances -= 1
else:
    print("Invalid input. Please enter a single letter or the entire word.")
...
```

Try use this:

```
...
if guess not in lettersguessed:
    lettersguessed.append(guess)

if eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed) == eng_word:
    print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the correct word: " + eng_word)
    break
else:
    chances -=1
    if guess in eng_word:
        print("Correct Letter!)")
    else:
        print("Incorrect! Guess again!")
...
```

Follow all code:

```
import random

def choose_eng_word():
    eng_wb = ["world", "woman", "place", "group", "problem", "house", "system", "thing", "point",
             "family", "fact", "money", "child", "water", "state", "month", "person", "company",
             "hand", "part", "instance", "government", "number", "question", "issue", "service",
             "friend", "example", "business", "job", "complication", "authority", "government",
             "development", "education", "community", "president", "hospital", "information",
             "research", "history", "communication", "experience", "decision", "support",
             "understanding", "relationship", "variation", "daughter"]
    eng_word = random.choice(eng_wb).upper()
    return eng_word

def eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, guesses):
    eng_word_in_prog = ""
    for letter in eng_word:
        if letter in guesses:
            eng_word_in_prog += letter
        else:
            eng_word_in_prog += "*"
    return eng_word_in_prog

def eng_main(eng_word):
    lettersguessed = []
    chances = int(len(eng_word) + 4)
    print("You are looking for a word that is " + str(len(eng_word)) + " letters long.")

    while True:
        if chances != 0:
            print("\nYou have " + str(chances) + " chances left.")
            print("Word so far: " + eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed))
            print("Letters guessed: " + str(lettersguessed))
            guess = input("Guess: ").upper()

            if guess == eng_word:
                print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the correct word: " + eng_word)
                break
            elif len(guess) == 1 and guess not in lettersguessed:
                lettersguessed.append(guess)
                if guess in eng_word:
                    print("Correct Letter!")
                else:
                    print("Incorrect! Guess again!")
                if eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed) == eng_word:
                    print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the correct word: " + eng_word)
                    break
                chances -= 1
            else:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter a single letter or the entire word.")
        else:
            print("\nWhoops! You ran out of guesses. The correct word was " + eng_word)
            break

while True:
    eng_word = choose_eng_word()
    eng_main(eng_word)
    if input("Would you like to continue? ").lower().startswith("n"):
        break
```

Comment: Thank you! removing the indexing was definitely the fix that I needed. In regards to the other suggestions, it looks like when I swapped my code for them, the final "else" kept breaking the syntax, I'm not sure why.

Comment: I put all code, maybe can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a `while True` loop in the global scope as Python is an sequential interpreted language that means that the lines of code get executed in an sequential matter the first line, then the second then the third. Plus, Python respects scopes therefore, you have to make sure that the variables you are using globally (aka outside your functions, methods, or classes) are defined globally. And in return you can use inside the functions, or classes' scopes global variables.

As you say your Error is on line 54

```
NameError: name 'eng_main' is not defined
```

The problem lies in the function not defined in the global scope (This could be due to indentation (spaces/tabs before the insides of a function or class) very common with newbies in Python) it is defined in the `choose_eng_word()` function's scope. So in order to access the function you will just need to remove the indentation as the modified code below.

```py
import random

def choose_eng_word():
  eng_wb = ["world", "woman", "place", "group", "problem", "house", "system", "thing", "point", "family", "fact", "money", "child", "water", "state", "month", "person", "company", "hand", "part", "instance", "government", "number", "question", "issue", "service", "friend", "example", "business", "job", "complication", "authority", "government", "development", "education", "community", "president", "hospital", "information", "research", "history", "communication", "experience", "decision", "support", "understanding", "relationship", "variation", "daughter"]
  
  eng_word = random.choice(eng_wb).upper()
  return eng_word
  
def eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, guesses):
  eng_word_in_prog = "" 
  for letter in eng_word:
    if letter in guesses:
        eng_word_in_prog += letter
    else:
        eng_word_in_prog += "*"
  return eng_word_in_prog



def eng_main(eng_word):
  lettersguessed = []
  chances = int(len(eng_word) + 4)
  print("you are looking for a word that is " + str(len(eng_word)) + " letters long.")
  while True:
    if chances != 0:
        print("\nYou have " + str(chances) + " chances left.")
        print("Word so far: " + eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed))
        print("letters guessed: " + str(lettersguessed))
        guess = input("Guess: ").upper()[0]
  
        if guess not in lettersguessed:
            lettersguessed.append(guess)
  
        if eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed) == eng_word:
            print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the correct word: " + eng_word)
            break
        else:
            chances -=1
            if guess in eng_word:
                print("Correct Letter!)")
            else:
                print("Incorrect! Guess again!")
    else:
        print("\nWhoops! You ran out of guesses. The correct word was " + eng_word)
        break
    

while True:
    eng_word = choose_eng_word()
    eng_main(eng_word) 
    if input("Would you like to continue?").lower().startswith("n"):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in those lines

```
guess = input("Guess: ") 
instead of guess = input("Guess: ").upper()[0]
```

Because with [0] guess always will be only the first letter

Next you need to write additional condition:

```
if eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed) == eng_word or guess.upper() == eng_word:
```

this checks if guess is equal to word

here is whole code:

```
while True:
    if chances != 0:
        print("\nYou have " + str(chances) + " chances left.")
        print("Word so far: " + eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed))
        print("letters guessed: " + str(lettersguessed))
        guess = input("Guess: ")

        if guess.upper()[0] not in lettersguessed:
            lettersguessed.append(guess)

        if eng_word_in_prog(eng_word, lettersguessed) == eng_word or guess.upper() == eng_word:
            print("\nCongratulations! You guessed the correct word: " + eng_word)
            break
        else:
            chances -=1
            if guess in eng_word:
                print("Correct Letter!)")
            else:
                print("Incorrect! Guess again!")
    else:
        print("\nWhoops! You ran out of guesses. The correct word was " + eng_word)
        break
```